# SSIS cannot determine the correct datatype of the column

Tags: ssis, ssis-data-types

I have a simple SSIS package that picks data from Oracle database and inserts data to sql server. In DataFlow I have 3 tasks:

1. I have a OLE DB source that runs a very simple query. Select
   Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7 From Table.
2. Then I have a Data conversion task that converts col6 and
   col7 from unicode STRING[DT_WSTR] to STRING[DT_STR].
3. OLE DB Destination(sql server).

> ERROR: SSIS turns the OLE DB Source Task to Red and displays the
>   following error:
>
> There was an error with output column "Col3" (23) on output "OLE DB
>   Source Output" (11). The column status returned was: "Text was
>   truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code
>   page.".
>
> The "output column "Col3" (23)" failed because truncation occurred,
>   and the truncation row disposition on "output column "OS_VISIT_ID"
>   (23)" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on
>   the specified object of the specified component.

But Col3 is not text its a Number, and SSIS is detecting it as unicode STRING[DT_WSTR]. 
I even tried to convert Col3 to Numeric in Data Conversion task before it goes to OLE DB Destination. But I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Click Error Output - choose truncation, and select redirect row. Then add a Union stage after the source to connect both the regular output with the "error" rows. Attach a data viewer to the error line and see what kind of data it's complaining on. It will now run the task as normal.

PS: Some oddball provider drivers -require- you to do this, even though it never "fails" per se. For example Acucorp XBDC drivers (that read some strange db format flat files) - will fail if you don't setup an error output, even though every row will go through the normal output once you have the error row configured.